# Can I alert a struts2 property tag in jsp?

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

Question as above, is there anyway I can alert() in jsp?
I tried doing that but my jquery failed.

This is what I tried:

```
alert(<s:property value='fab'/>);
```

Comment: So if you tried something you should post your attempt. At the moment I (and probably many others) have no idea what you are trying to do

Comment: Well, I tried doing this:
    alert(<s:property value='fab'/>);
it says in my firebug: 
    missing ) after argument list
and I tried doing this:
    alert("Test :"+<s:property value= 'fab'/>);

and it didn't work as well.

And I thought my question was pretty straightforward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing quotes:

```
alert("<s:property value='fab'/>");
```

... and if you want to escape JavaScript like Dave Newton said, you should do it like so:

```
alert("<s:property value='fab' escapeJavaScript='true'/>");
```

You can find more info about `property` tag [there](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/property.html).

Comment: @user1287402 With the caveat that the property should be JavaScript-escaped.

Answer (score 2):

The alert function needs to be supplied with a valid javascript object so that is can alert.

Most commonly, in my case at least, this would be a string object which you can do like so...

```
alert("My Text");
```

alternatively, you can alert an object such as an integer...

```
alert(1);
```

or a reference to an object...

```
var myObject = {};
alert(myObject);
```

---

In your case perhaps you want to try alerting a string as follows...

```
alert("<s:property value='fab'/>");
```

...notice the use of quotes to enclose the value, this tells the javascript parser that it should be treated as a string.

Comment: Your idea of dynamically-set values is incorrect; JSP (and the tags they contain) are evaluated before any JavaScript is run.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I see, don't use JSP so didn't realise this was part of that. I will remove that part